# How to solve the problem of java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to set the a new position which is the global solution for the algorithm. I read the new position from a text file called (hh) but when I trying to pass it via the code line p.setNeighborhoodPosition(f,val1);, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:426)
    at PSOFS.Particle.setNeighborhoodPosition(Particle.java:177)
    at PSOFS.Main.main(Main.java:213)
```

Here is the code that I used

```
     Particle p = new Particle();
          if (s.getProblem().isBetter(newFitness, oldFitness)) {
              p.setNeighborhoodFitness(newFitness);
 String sc1 = new Scanner( new File("hh.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
             sc1 = sc1.replaceAll("\\[","").replaceAll("\\]","");
            String[] doublesAsStrings1 = sc1.split(", ");
           double [] num=new double[doublesAsStrings1.length];
          for( int f = 0; f < doublesAsStrings1.length; f++ ){
              num[f] = Double.parseDouble(doublesAsStrings1[f]);
                  p.setNeighborhoodPosition(f,num[f]);}
```

the two lines that cause the error are

```
public void setNeighborhoodPosition(int index, double value) {
        this._neighborhood_position.set(index, value);
    }

         p.setNeighborhoodPosition(f,num[f]);
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't call `set(0, ...)` when the list is empty. The `set` method cannot be used to grow the list size. So says the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`set(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-): *Throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is out of range (index < 0 || **index >= size()**)*. Use `add(...)` to grow the list.

Comment: thanks@Andreas for reply. So how can I send the new solution to the method if not via the set method?

Comment: The `set` method won't "grow" the list.   Use `add` or `insert`.   Or use an array instead of a list ...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) and [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c), use method [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) of class `java.util.ArrayList`, e.g.

```
public void setNeighborhoodPosition(double value) {
    this._neighborhood_position.add(value);
}
```